# what is the best feature to describe regular texture?

Tags: image, textures, feature-detection

everyone,now I have some pictures which have regular texture.
I want to ask that does there exist any features to describe the regular texture,and they should be some features which are better than glcm,wavelet transformation and so on,because these features are not just only for regular,but also not-regular
I just want a feature which can deal with regular texture best.

Thanks a lot!

who else has more methods?I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best regular texture matching method often used for matching rectified stereo-images uses ratio histogram. For example, let us say you have a window W1 of regular texture in one image and W2 of in the other image. Note that, W1 and W2 both comprise of the same number of pixels.

Now, calculate the ratio of the corresponding pixels in W1 and W2 and fill these ratio values in histogram with bin ranging from 0.8 to 1.25 and binsize=0.025 (depending on the noise in your image) i.e, increment the histogram bin value by one if the ratio falls in that range. In case your image is RGB, calculate this ratio for all the bands and simply dump the ratios in the same histogram.

For matching, you choose the histogram with the highest value in a single bin. For details, please follow the procedure described in this paper, 
[Zitnick04](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64201/zitnicksig04.pdf).

I hope it helps :-)

Comment: let me have a look.Thank you very much.

Comment: Please upvote if you find it useful :P